# AWS ECS is taking Secret Key instead of Value from Secret Manager for Amazon ECS tasks on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I have a few ECS containers and I needed to inject sensitive information into them. I created a secret in the AWS secret manager and added all the keys and values. I added the in-line policy for reading the secret in the taskExecutionRole. I also added the secret in my task definition, the example is given below.

```
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountID>:secret:staging/environment-12345"
        }
      ]
```

Now I have 2 containers, one is an AWS Fargate which is running a ruby on rails web server. This container detected the secret and worked fine without any issues. I have another container with the console of said server and it is running on EC2. That container is throwing an error as it is taking the name of the secret instead of the value. A screenshot of the log is attached below :-

[AWS ECS Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JflWz.png)

I made sure my container instance must have version 1.37.0 or later of the container agent. I also doubled checked my task execution role. I also checked both instances of the container are attached to the same VPC. I also validated that the parameters of task definitions are correct.

If you need more information, I can provide it to you.

Edit 1:

This is the code we are using to read the environment variables. We are running this same code in AWS Fargate as well as localhost. This works fine in localhost as well as in AWS Fargate. I don't think the solution to the problem lies in the code below but still adding it as a reference.

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_sigv4'
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL'] do |f|
    f.use FaradayMiddleware::Gzip
    f.request :aws_sigv4,
            credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
            service: 'es',
            region: '<region>'
end
```

I also printed an env variable which doesn't exist in the rails console. The output is the following:-

```
3.0.0 :002 > ENV['BOO']
 => nil
```

If the variable doesn't exist, we will get nil. However, in our case we are getting some garbage value instead of nil.

Comment: Your container running on EC2 is not properly reading the environment variable. You need to show the code in that container for reading the environment variable. You are missing a `$` or something.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for the response. I have edited my question and added the snippet of code to read the environment variables.